# IIS rewrite rules for subdomain and nonexistent files

Tags: php, iis, rewrite

Setup:

- I know how to use a rewrite rule to route urls to a routing script such as router.php.
- I know how to use a rewrite rule to route urls containing a subdomain to subfolders in the document root.

What I really need is to combine the two concepts.  If I have http://sub.example.com/api, how do I get router.php to handle the request as if it was originally http://example.com/sub/api?  The router rewrite rules seems to not get the results of the subdomain rewrite rule (the subdomain is left off the end of the url leaving just /api).

Comment: We can't help you effectively unless you show us the rewrite rules that you tried to use.  It may or may not also help to show us the PHP router code.